# Cannot see the name of the current virtual environment in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

- I'm using Python 3 on Linux
- When I open a new terminal, the name of virtual environment is not shown.
- I can install python packages in this (unknown) environment with `pip install`

1. What is the name of this current virtual environment ?
2. How can I get the repository which this virtual environment uses to install packages (via pip) ?

Comment: have you considered using `which python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I open a new terminal, the name of virtual environment is not shown.

The name cannot be shown, because in order to see the name you must first activate the virtual environment. You have to

1. create a virtual env in a folder
2. cd into that folder
3. run `sh bin/activate`

Then, the name will be shown.
Without an active virtual environment, pip will install the packages into

- `/usr/lib/python3` when run with admin rights (e.g. using `sudo`)
- `$HOME/.local/lib/python3` when run without admin rights

And the repository the packages will be downloaded from should normally be [pypi.org](http://pypi.org).